# How do I access my personal vehicles?

Tags: xbox-one, grand-theft-auto-online

How do I access my personal vehicles as I have 12 but no clue as to access them?!??

Comment: You can call you mechanic with your phone and select the vehicle you want

Answer (score 0):

I'm fairly certain your question has been asked before, but I have no way to find out, so I will answer it anyway.

To access your personal vehicles, you simply have to call your mechanic on your in-game phone. As long as you are in an area where the mechanic can deliver the vehicle, and it's not impounded or destroyed, he will deliver it to you. There is a short cooldown on this, however. Also, if you have not paid your mechanic within the last 24 hours in-game, he will be unavailable until the next time you pay him.
Alternatively, you can visit your garage to grab a vehicle, or, if you already have one out, but it's not nearby, you can use the interaction menu to call it to you.